# MS access, write query in VBA and show result in text box

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have this query which works ok.

I want to write this query in Access VBA and when i execute this query to show me result in text field in my form. 
On my form i have text box which is name"Result"
So i want when execute this query to show on my text box which is name"Result" But i want to write this in VBA. How to do that?

```
SELECT ORDINACIJA.Exam, Count(*) AS total
FROM ORDINACIJA
WHERE ORDINACIJA.Exam='EHO ABDOMENA' AND ORDINACIJA.month='JANUARY'
GROUP BY ORDINACIJA.Exam;
```

Comment: While writing and running an SQL query in VBA is reasonably simple, you can't just simply "print" the output (which, in General, is a two-dimensional table or recordset) into a textfield (which usually holds only one value).

You could consider using one either a gridview, a listbox or the a split-form, that shows the Access datasheetview and UserForm

Comment: But in textfield i need just one value. It will be total rows from my query. For example, total rows is 530.So in that field it shout write 530. This is just statistics so i do not need to write in database. Is that possible?

Comment: Check out domain aggregate functions, in particular DCount and DlookUp. You can set a textbox control source to a domain aggregate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need SQL for this. In VBA, you can use the `DCount` function:

```
Dim lngCount As Long

lngCount = DCount("Exam", _
                  "ORDINACIJA", _
                  "ORDINACIJA.Exam='EHO ABDOMENA' AND ORDINACIJA.month='JANUARY'")

Result.Text = lngCount
```

But a better solution is to set the textbox's "Control Source" property to the following:

```
=DCount("Exam", "ORDINACIJA", "ORDINACIJA.Exam='EHO ABDOMENA' AND ORDINACIJA.month='JANUARY'")
```

That way, the textbox's value will be correct when the form opens, and additionally, whenever there is a need to update the value (e.g. if the table's data has changed), just execute the following in VBA:

```
Result.Requery
```

Comment: MJH, where this to write? Do i this code to write in VBA? And what code to write in text field? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much i succeed

Answer (score 0):

You can assign he Query to a string variable, and then use CurrentDB.OpenRecordset to execute the query, like  so:

```
sub DoMyQuery()
dim S as String
dim R as recordset
  S = "SELECT ORDINACIJA.Exam, Count(*) AS total "& _
      "FROM ORDINACIJA "& _
      "WHERE ORDINACIJA.Exam='EHO ABDOMENA' AND ORDINACIJA.month='JANUARY' "& _
      "GROUP BY ORDINACIJA.Exam;"
  Set R = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(S)
  ' do what ever needs to be done with data returned here
  R.close
end Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok this code i need to write in VBA. But what code to write in text box ?